# How to make accordion auto sort alphabetically on h3 tag string?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sorting, accordion

I am trying to get this HTML below to auto sort based on the h3 header. I am using a WordPress plugin called SIS Accordion and the client wants to have the accordion list he creates to sort alphabetically without any adjustments in the admin area. Currently he would have to change the date of the published accordion post to change the sorting. The Plugin support area has not responded with my question on auto sorting. So I am hoping this community may have a suggestion using jquery.

In my example below the "First Line" should be automatically sorted to show up first and "Last Line" is reordered to fall below it and "Very Last Line" falls to the bottom on page load.

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Last Line</h3>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis arcu non turpis consectetur faucibus quis ut velit. Mauris semper augue in tellus suscipit, at dictum quam congue.</div>
<h3>Very Last Line</h3>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis arcu non turpis consectetur faucibus quis ut velit. Mauris semper augue in tellus suscipit, at dictum quam congue.
</div>
<h3>First Line</h3>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis arcu non turpis consectetur faucibus quis ut velit. Mauris semper augue in tellus suscipit, at dictum quam congue.
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
        $("#accordion")
        .accordion({
            header: "> h3",
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
        })
        .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "h3",
            sorting: true,
            stop: function() {
                stop = true;
            }
        });

});
```

See my fiddle below for code examples. Thanks for any help you can provide.
http://jsfiddle.net/Cascus2/dh2qpm0p/

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the most efficient, but it's not hard to sort them. It's slightly complicated by the fact that each entry is a pair of siblings (the `h3` and the `div` following it), rather than being in a single container.

But this seems to work (doesn't seem to matter whether you do it before or after calling the accordion plugin): [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh2qpm0p/1/)

```
$(function() {
    var accordion = $("#accordion");

    // Get an array of jQuery objects containing each h3 and the div that
    // follows it
    var entries = $.map(accordion.children("h3").get(), function(entry) {
        var $entry = $(entry);
        return $entry.add($entry.next());
    });

    // Sort the array by the h3's text
    entries.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.filter("h3").text().localeCompare(b.filter("h3").text());
    });

    // Put them in the right order in the container
    $.each(entries, function() {
        this.detach().appendTo(accordion);
    });


    accordion
        .accordion({
            header: "> h3",
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
        })
        .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "h3",
            sorting: true,
            stop: function() {
                stop = true;
            }
        });
});
```

If you're changing the accordion dynamically, you'll need to repeat the sort, or (better) when adding be sure to insert in the correct location.

Comment: Thank you T.J. Crowder. This worked perfectly. WordPress was pulling in some later JQuery libraries (1.11.0 and UI of 1.10.4) so I linked (in the footer) 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2 and then linked in the Script above and it worked. So for those who think the latest JQuery will always work...no so much. :)